# calendar not displaying in my customised magento2 theme but is coming in luma(default)

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, magento2

I'm sharing with you my js code in which conflicts are occurring. It's not including files such as `minicart/content.html`, `authentication-popup.html`, `Template/collection.html`, `Template/messages.html`, `checkout/captcha.html` in the console whereas it's in luma (default) theme:

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                var date = new Date();
                var d = date.getDate();
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var y = date.getFullYear();
                var calendar_mode = '';
var switchMode = '<?php echo $block->getScopeConfig('events/calendar_setting/allow_switch_mode'); ?>';
var defaultMode = '<?php echo $block->getScopeConfig('events/calendar_setting/default_view_mode'); ?>';
                if (switchMode == '1') {
                    calendar_mode = 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay';
                }
                var events = <?php echo $eventsJson; ?>;
                jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    <?php if ($locale != 'en') { ?>
                        locale: "<?php echo $locale; ?>",
                    <?php } ?>
                    editable: true,
                    displayEventEnd:true,
                    disableDragging: true,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: calendar_mode
                    },
                    defaultView: defaultMode,
                    eventTextColor: 'white',
                    timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                    events: events,
                    eventMouseover: eventMouseoverFunc,
                    eventMouseout: eventMouseoutFunc
                });



    </script>
```

Comment: is there's an error in console ?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);

Comment: & ------------>   TypeError: window.checkout is undefined
 

autocomplete: window.checkout.autocomplete,

Answer (score 1):

okay so while debugging i found out that the conflict was occurring due to 2 major issues:

1. changing the class of jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({ to jQuery('#any_unique_id').fullCalendar({  and parallely changing the calendar div id to the same div id='calendar'> to div id='any_unique _id'>
2. changing the require function to :

   ```
       require(['jquery', 'mage/mage','fullcalendar', 'moment'<?php if ($locale != 'en') { ?>, 'locale_all'<?php } ?>], function($){
   ```

And finally it worked!